# Different content on page load in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, random

I'm trying to find a way to load different content (basically `<img>` and `<a>`) within divs, on every page load.

I know it is possible to do, since many sites use "dynamic" or "rotating" banners which either load different content on a defined interval or on page load.

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by making an array of objects containing the URLs of the image and the link, then using `Math.random()` to select a random one.

```
var banners = [
    { img: '/images/1.png', a: 'page1.htm'},
    { img: '/images/2.png', a: 'page2.htm'},
    { img: '/images/3.png', a: 'page3.htm'},
    { img: '/images/4.png', a: 'page4.htm'},
    { img: '/images/5.png', a: 'page5.htm'},
    { img: '/images/6.png', a: 'page6.htm'}
];
var banner = banners[Math.floor(Math.random() * banners.length)];
document.write('<a href="' + banner.a + '"><img src="' + banner.img + '"></a>');
```

You might well want something more complex than this, but this should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/random-image